# Is Google Cloud SQL highly available by default?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

On [this page](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/faq#benefits) it says

> You can access a familiar, **highly available** SQL database

but then on the same page [down below](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/faq#supportmysqlfeatures) it says

> Unsupported Features: MySql replication

Can anyone clarify this?

Answer (score 5):

Each Cloud SQL instance replicates your data at the storage level, rather than within MySQL. So a single MySQL instance writes every byte multiple times in multiple geographic locations. Even if an entire datacenter becomes available a new MySQL instance can be spun up in a new location and carry on serving your data.

See https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/faq#replication